# jQuery to only show labels of checked checkboxes and hide the unchecked ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I have this setup:

```
<style>.selectit{display:none;}</style>
<div id="foo">
<label class="selectit">
<input type="checkbox" name="one" id="one" checked>
One
</label>
<label class="selectit">
<input type="checkbox" name="two" id="two">
Two
</label>
<label class="selectit">
<input type="checkbox" name="three" id="three" checked>
Three
</label>
</div>
```

I only want to display the Label tags for the checked inputs and hide the labels for others.

something like show() for the checked inputs labels and hide() for the unchecked ones.

example of working code:

```
<style>.selectit{display:none;}</style>
<div id="foo">
<label class="selectit" style="display:block">
<input type="checkbox" name="one" id="one" checked>
One
</label>
<label class="selectit">
<input type="checkbox" name="two" id="two">
Two
</label>
<label class="selectit" style="display:block">
<input type="checkbox" name="three" id="three" checked>
Three
</label>
</div>
```

or maybe perhaps, make a new div and only show the text of the checked labels in that div.

```
<style>.selectit{display:none;}</style>
<div id="foo">
<label class="selectit">
<input type="checkbox" name="one" id="one" checked>
One
</label>
<label class="selectit">
<input type="checkbox" name="two" id="two">
Two
</label>
<label class="selectit">
<input type="checkbox" name="three" id="three" checked>
Three
</label>
</div>
<div id="output">One - Three</div>
```

is this even possible? or do I need to do this by appending a div that searches the whole checkboxes? Any help is appreciated because I've exhausted all my options already and I'm out of ideas. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd build an object with references to each checked checkbox, and an object with references to each label. Then I'd go through the list of labels, and see if the `for` attribute matched any of the checked checkboxes. Also, add `for` attributes. It's good for accessibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter checked checkboxes using `filter` method.

```
$('#foo input[type=checkbox]').filter(function(){
      return this.checked;
}).prev('label').show();
```

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer*: This answer is just based on your title question

---

I'd go with pure *CSS* for that. Like

```
label {
    display: none;
} 

input:checked + label {
    display: block;
}
```

You would just need to adjust your markup a little.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZpmGd/

Comment: That's just neat and as I can see works when the labels are nested correctly. But I'm editing a plugin and I really don't have the knowledge to edit the plugin maker's original markup. I wish I could use pure CSS to do this, cause this works so good I'm just regretting using jQuery. although the jQuery method seems like the easiest for me at the moment. Kudos for the answer.